# exclamation mark is appears in email message body using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I m using phpmailer for sending emails in my website. My code works fine but sometimes in email message body contains exclamation mark at random places. My code is as follows:

```
$mail->SetFrom(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_NAME); //emailid of sender(admin)                
$mail->Subject = 'Subject here.'; //subject of email
$mail->AddAddress(Address here); //emailid of user(recipient)
$content = 'some html code here';

$mail->MsgHTML($content); //this is body of email
$mail->Send();
```

This works fine. But can't find why exclamation comes sometimes.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Exclamation mark `!` or question mark `?` ?? Often, if the client viewing the HTML mail misinterprets the character set (because your message misreported it), invalid characters will appear as `?`.

Comment: May need `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's because the email messages can't have more than 998 characters on one line.

Try adding,

```
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
```

Comment: check this out, http://www.tinyfrogsoftware.com/the-story-of-the-rogue-exclamation-mark-or-how-i-lost-4-hours-of-my-life/

Hope it helps.

Comment: or try adding `$content = wordwrap($content, 50);`  after `$content = 'some html code here';`

Comment: Could you explain why this is the case or a reference to why it can't handle more than 998 characters?

Comment: @StefanDunn The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many implementations which send, receive, or store Internet Message Format messages that simply cannot handle more than 998 characters on a line.  For more details [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-2.1.1)

Comment: Tinyfrogsoftware link was dead. Here's a live archive version - https://web.archive.org/web/20100424013747/http://www.tinyfrogsoftware.com/the-story-of-the-rogue-exclamation-mark-or-how-i-lost-4-hours-of-my-life/

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late but there is an alternate solution that worked for me:

Use this line to encode your entire message using base64:

```
$message = chunk_split(base64_encode($message));
```

Then, append this your header:

```
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
```

That will tell the mail client that your message is base64 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using PHPmailer then only one line of code should help:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
```

this will do Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 and chunk_split(base64_encode($message)) internally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, after long searching I have found that you should wordwrap your HTML

```
$emailContent = '<p>some large html</p>';
$mail->msgHTML(wordwrap($emailContent, 50));
```